# Python: How can i send more requests as fast as possible?

Tags: python, python-requests

i am currently working on a program which sends post requests to a API to change the username of an account.

Using multithreading i can reach around 20 requests in 0.72 seconds, But what i need to be able to do is to send around 1000+ in 1 second.

post request:

```
snipe = requests.post('https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/private/name', headers= {'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}"}, json= auth)
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use `asyncio` and `aiohttp`

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/fast-and-async-in-python-accelerate-your-requests-using-asyncio-62dafca83c33) on how to go async

Comment: [Here's the list of async primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) you can use to run the posts concurrently

Comment: [Another useful post](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-boost-your-python-apps-using-httpx-and-asynchronous-calls-9cfe6f63d6ad) on the subject. I too recommend [Httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx)